# Can't login to SQL server database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I created a backup of a client's database from their host. I restored it to my local machine using SQL 2008 management studio. Everything appeared to go fine. However I cannot get any logins to work for it. I've created new logins and assigned them as the dbo for the database, yet in my asp.net page or visual studio's data connection pane, I can't login to the database.

I've even tried assigning the system admin that can access all other database to this db and it too cannot login.  Would there be an option on the database itself that I need to set?  Thanks.

Comment: Can you **show us** your connection string?? What **exact** error do you get??

Comment: are those accounts that you created able to successfully login to the database through the SQL Management Studio? I am assuming those are SQL accounts rather than Windows accounts right?

Comment: Data Source=hplaptop\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=gallerydb;User Id=gallery_user_RW;Password=userpassword  These are all sql accounts, NOT windows accounts.  My windows account can login through management studio which is how I created the database.  But if I use the same credentials, integrated security, in the connectionstring, my windows account can't login either.

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server has two types of user accounts.  The first is the server-wide "login".  The second is the database specific "user".  The link between the two is a SID, a big unique number.

Now if you restore a database, it will only restore users, not logins.  That means the link between logins and users is lost.

This script will repair the users by calling the system procedure `sp_change_users_login`.  This procedure matches logins to users based on name, if the SID does not match:

```
use <YourDbNameHere>

declare usr_cur cursor forward_only read_only for
    select  distinct sysusers.name
    from    sysusers 
    join    master.dbo.syslogins 
    on      sysusers.name = master.dbo.syslogins.name
    where   sysusers.issqluser <> 0

declare @usr sysname;

open usr_cur
fetch next from usr_cur into @usr;

while @@fetch_status = 0 
    begin
    if @usr <> 'dbo'
        exec sp_change_users_login 'Auto_Fix', @usr 

    fetch next from usr_cur into @usr
    end

close usr_cur
deallocate usr_cur
```

Run it on your local machine, and the logins should work again.

Comment: But I'm creating new brand new logins and assigning them as users to the database and they are not working.  And as I mentioned, I've also assigned the system admin login as a user to the database which can't login.  I tried running your script but still no one can login to the database.

Comment: @Geoff Swartz: Right, so what error message do you get?  Can you login to the "master" database?  If so, what error do you get when you try to "use RestoredDb" ?

Comment: The error I get when I try to login to the database in question is "login failed for user gallery_user_RW" or any other login username.  I can login to the master database using the main system admin account just fine, but not the gallery database.

Comment: @Geoff Swartz: What does it say when you use the system admin account to execute `select state_desc, user_access_desc from sys.databases where name = 'RestoredDB'` ?

Comment: It's coming back ONLINE MULTI_USER

Comment: @Geoff Swartz: Hmm, then I'm out of ideas.  Try [asking on DBA](http://dba.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem was but I went to the restoredDB>tasks>generate scripts to a new query window.  I created a new db and ran this query window against it and then did a table data import task from the restoredDB to the new one.  Now I can connect with users no problem.  Something must have gotten screwed up in the original backup... but at least I'm up and running again.